# nodejs: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My current script looks like so:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'); //no errors here
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build(); //causes problems
```

The error looks like this:

```
(node:27161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.10.267518,platform=Linux 4.15.0-kali2-amd64 x86_64)
at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/root/automate/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:585:15)
at parseHttpResponse (/root/automate/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:533:13)
at Executor.execute (/root/automate/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:468:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:27161) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27161) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The google chrome browser never launches either.

My node version is

v10.3.0

npm version is

```
6.1.0
```

chromedriver version is

```
2.10.267518
```

My OS is Kali-Linux

Google Chrome version:

```
67.0.3396.62
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are 101 things that could cause this, and we have no idea what they might be in your case. Do you have Chrome installed, under the expected name, on the path? Is the driver up-to-date?

Comment: yeah, they're all up to date

Comment: Really? I thought the latest Chromedriver was two-dot-thirtysomething, not two-dot-10. Old chromedrivers will not support later versions of Chrome.